# How do I know how many sub-shells deep I am?

Tags: command-line

Sometimes I do things such as starting a sub-shell from vim with `:sh`.  How do I know if I'm in a sub-shell where `exit` will just return me out one level, vs. being in the outermost shell where `exit` will log me out or close my session.

Is there some kind of Inception totem I can spin or something to know how many levels deep I am?

Comment: Related at vi.stackexchange.com : [How do I know i am in a shell from vi command :sh?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/12311/how-do-i-know-i-am-in-a-shell-from-vi-command-sh)

Comment: Hi! One quick way to see if you're in a subshell or not is to `echo $0`. If it's the toplevel shell, it will probably start with a dash. (This is true at least for bash, and the dash means that it's a so-called login shell.)

Comment: Cross-site duplicate of [How many shells deep I am?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/373704/23408)

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You can use the command `pstree` (that comes by default with Ubuntu). Here is example - currently I'm having only one open terminal window on WSL:

```bsh
User@Wsl:~$ pstree
init─┬─init───bash───pstree
     └─{init}

User@Wsl:~$ bash
User@Wsl:~$ sh
$ bash
User@Wsl:~$ pstree
init─┬─init───bash───bash───sh───bash───pstree
     └─{init}
```

Within an actual Linux/Ubuntu environment the process tree will be more complicated. We can filter the tree by the option `-s` that will show the parents of a selected process. So our command could be **`pstree -s $$`**, where `$$` is an environment variable that contains the current PID:

```bsh
User@Ubuntu:~$ pstree -s $$
systemd──lightdm──lightdm──upstart──gnome-terminal-──bash──pstree

User@Ubuntu:~$ bash
User@Ubuntu:~$ sh
$ bash
User@Ubuntu:~$ pstree -s $$
systemd──lightdm──lightdm──upstart──gnome-terminal-──bash──bash──sh──bash──pstree
```

References:

- [SuperUser: How to get parent PID of a given process in GNU/Linux from command line?](https://superuser.com/q/150117/664884)
- [HowtoForge: Linux pstree Command Tutorial for Beginners](https://www.howtoforge.com/linux-pstree-command/)

---

**Add indicator to the shell's prompt:** Based on the @waltinator's [idea](https://askubuntu.com/a/1177193/566421), in order to have a counter in the front of the prompt for several different shells when the level is deeper than one, I've added the lines, shown below the demo, at the bottom of the relevant *run commands* (`~/.*rc`) files.

I've made tests on WSL, Ubuntu 16.04, Ubuntu 18.04 (server/desktop), Ubuntu 19.04, within gnome-terminal, tty and ssh session. Here is how this works:

[image]

The limitation is that: the counter works only for 13-14 levels of depth, depending on the OS. I do not intend to investigate the reasons :)

- `bash` > `.bashrc`:

  ```bsh
  DEPTH=$(($(pstree -s $$ | sed -r 's/-+/\n/g' | grep -Ec '\<(bash|zsh|sh|dash|ksh|csh|tcsh)\>') - 1))
  if (( DEPTH > 1 )); then PS1=$DEPTH:$PS1; fi
  ```
- `csh` and `tcsh` > `.cshrc`:

  ```bsh
  @ DEPTH = `pstree -s $$ | sed -r 's/-+/\n/g' | grep -Ec '\<(bash|zsh|sh|dash|ksh|csh|tcsh)\>'` - 0
  if ( $DEPTH > 1 ) then; set prompt="$DEPTH":"$prompt"; endif
  ```
- `zsh` > `.zshrc`:

  ```bsh
  DEPTH=$(($(pstree -s $$ | sed -r 's/-+/\n/g' | grep -Ec '\<(bash|zsh|sh|dash|ksh|csh|tcsh)\>') - 1))
  if (( DEPTH > 1 )); then PROMPT=$DEPTH:$PROMPT; fi
  ```
- `ksh` > `.kshrc`:

  ```bsh
  DEPTH=$(($(pstree -s $$ | sed -r 's/\-+/\n/g' | grep -Ec '\<(bash|zsh|sh|dash|ksh|csh|tcsh)\>') - 0))
  if (( DEPTH > 1 )); then PS1="$DEPTH":"$PS1"'$ '; fi
  ```
- `sh` that is actually `dash` on Ubuntu - here the things are little bit complicated and wired (read the references below for more information):

  1. Edit the `~/.profile` file and add the following line at the bottom:

     ```bsh
     ENV=$HOME/.shrc; export ENV
     ```
  2. Create the file `~/.shrc` with the following content, note `ksh` also reads the `$ENV`:

     ```bsh
     #!/bin/dash
     DEPTH=$(pstree -s $$ | sed -r 's/-+/\n/g' | grep -Ec '\<(bash|zsh|sh|dash|ksh|csh|tcsh)\>')
     if [ "$0" != 'ksh' ]; then DEPTH=$((DEPTH - 1)); fi
     if [ "$DEPTH" -gt 1 ]; then export PS1='$DEPTH:\$ '; fi
     ```

References:

- [The previous version of the answer, where the counter works only in Bash](https://askubuntu.com/revisions/1177127/4)
- [Unix&Linux: Is there an invoked file for dash and sh as non login shells in /etc directory?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/469563/201297)
- [Ubuntu Manuals: Dash (read the BUGS section)](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man1/dash.1.html)
- [UnixWare 7 Documentation: The Korn shell `.profile` and `.kshrc`](http://uw714doc.xinuos.com/en/SHL_custom/The_Korn_shell_profile_and_kshrc.html)

---

**Create a command that will output the depth:** Another option is to create shell command that will output the depth. For this purpose create the executable file `/usr/local/bin/depth` (thus it should be accessible system wide):

```bsh
sudo touch /usr/local/bin/depth
sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/depth
```

Edit the file with your favorite editor and add the following lines as its content:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

SHELLS='(bash|zsh|sh|dash|ksh|csh|tcsh)'
DEPTH=$(pstree -s $$ | sed -r 's/-+/\n/g' | grep -Ec "\<$SHELLS\>")

if [[ $@ =~ -v ]]
then
        pstree -s $$ | sed -r 's/-+/\n/g' | grep -E "\<$SHELLS\>" | cat -n
fi

echo "DEPTH: $DEPTH"

[[ $DEPTH -gt 1 ]] && exit 0 || exit 1
```

The above script has two options `-v` or `--verbose` that will output a list of the involved shells. And the another option that will check whether the depth is greater than one and based on this will return `exit 0` or `exit 1`, so you can use it in this way `depth && exit`. Here are few examples of usage:

```bsh
User@Ubuntu:~$ depth          # we are at the 1st level - bash
DEPTH: 1
User@Ubuntu:~$ sh           
$ csh                         # we are at the 2nd level - dash
Ubuntu:~% depth               # we are at the 3rd level - csh
DEPTH: 3
Ubuntu:~% ksh
$ depth -v                    # we are at the 4th level - ksh
     1  bash
     2  sh
     3  csh
     4  ksh
DEPTH: 4
$ depth && exit               # exit to the 3rd level - csh
DEPTH: 4
Ubuntu:~% depth && exit       # exit to the 2nd level - dash
DEPTH: 3
exit
$ depth && exit               # exit to the 1st level - bash
DEPTH: 2
User@Ubuntu:~$ depth && exit  # stay at the 1st level - bash
DEPTH: 1
User@Ubuntu:~$ depth && exit  # stay at the 1st level - bash
DEPTH: 1
```

---

**Comparison by the other solutions:** I spent some additional time to find out some weaknesses of the approaches provided here. I was able to imagine the following two cases (the capital letters are needed for better syntax highlighting):

- When `su` or `sudo -i` are involved:

  ```bsh
  User@Ubuntu:~$ ps | grep -Ec '\<(bash|zsh|sh|dash|ksh|csh|tcsh|su|sudo)\>'
  1
  User@Ubuntu:~$ echo $SHLVL
  1
  User@Ubuntu:~$ depth
  DEPTH: 1

  User@Ubuntu:~$ su spas
  Password:

  Spas@Ubuntu:~$ ps | grep -Ec '\<(bash|zsh|sh|dash|ksh|csh|tcsh|su|sudo)\>'
  1
  Spas@Ubuntu:~$ echo $SHLVL
  2
  Spas@Ubuntu:~$ depth
  DEPTH: 2

  Spas@Ubuntu:~$ sudo -i
  [sudo] password for spas:

  Root@Ubuntu:~# ps | grep -Ec '\<(bash|zsh|sh|dash|ksh|csh|tcsh|su|sudo)\>'
  3
  Root@Ubuntu:~# echo $SHLVL
  1
  Root@Ubuntu:~# depth
  DEPTH: 3
  ```
- When there a background process is launched:

  ```bsh
  User@Ubuntu:~$ bash
  User@Ubuntu:~$ ps | grep -Ec '\<(bash|zsh|sh|dash|ksh|csh|tcsh)\>'
  2
  User@Ubuntu:~$ echo $SHLVL
  2
  User@Ubuntu:~$ depth
  DEPTH: 2

  User@Ubuntu:~$ while true; do sleep 10; done &
  [1] 10886
  User@Ubuntu:~$ ps | grep -Ec '\<(bash|zsh|sh|dash|ksh|csh|tcsh)\>'
  3
  User@Ubuntu:~$ echo $SHLVL
  2
  User@Ubuntu:~$ depth
  DEPTH: 2

  # Note: $SHLVL is not supported only by sh/dash.  
  #       It works with all other tested shells: bash, zsh, csh, tcsh, ksh

  User@Ubuntu:~$ sh
  $ ps | grep -Ec '\<(bash|zsh|sh|dash|ksh|csh|tcsh)\>'
  4
  $ echo $SHLVL
  2
  $ depth
  DEPTH: 3
  ```

Comment: Now I'm puzzled about output I got on my system: `systemd───xfce4-terminal───bash───pstree`. Why is it this way?

Comment: @val: systemd is the init process, the parent of all other processes. You are apparently using `xfce4-terminal`, which launched a `bash` shell, within which you ran `pstree`, which reported itself and its parents. If you mean the lack of steps between systemd and xfce4-terminal, it could be that whatever launched xfce4-terminal died or disowned it, in which case it would be inherited by init.

Comment: Any reason not to read `SHLVL` ? Portability across processes and systems, I assume, but then pstree may not be installed..

Comment: Hello, @D.BenKnoble, as it is discussed under the @egmont's [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1177163/566421), `$SHLVL` is not supported by some shells. More specific, according to the environment from the demo above it is not supported only by `sh` (`dash`) - and this shell is not counted at all by this variable. On the other hand `pstree` is part of the package [psmisc](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/bionic/armhf/psmisc) that provides also `fuser`, `killall` and few others - it is main component of Ubuntu - I haven't installed it on the systems mentioned in this answer.

Answer (score 31):

Check the value of the `SHLVL` shell variable:

```
echo $SHLVL
```

Quoting from `bash`'s manual page:

```
SHLVL  Incremented by one each time an instance of bash is started.
```

It is also supported by `zsh`.

Comment: But sh is not counted, so the example given, with sh, would not have incremented SHLVL.  Still, this is something that might be useful for those not switching shells too much

Comment: @ubfan1 unless there's an overriding vimrc definition, `:sh` defaults to the user's login shell I think (it's really an abbreviated form of `:shell` rather than the name of a specific shell binary)

Comment: I'm not familiar with vim's details, but I've tried out `:sh` from `vim` before posting this answer, and it did increment the shell level for me. My login shell is bash.

Answer (score 9):

In my `.bashrc`, I use `$SHLVL` to adjust `$PS1`, by appending "`+`" signs to my `$SUBSHELL` variable:

```bsh
...
# set a variable to reflect SHLVL > 1 (Ubuntu 12.04)
if [[ $SHLVL -gt 1 ]] ; then
    export SUBSHELL="${SUBSHELL:+$SUBSHELL}+"
else
    export SUBSHELL=""
fi
...

if [[ "$color_prompt" = yes ]]; then
#             chroot?                       Depth      green       user@host nocolor  :   green      $PWD  red      (status) off   $ or # space             
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}${SUBSHELL}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[1;31m\]($?)\[\033[00m\]\$ '
else
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}${SUBSHELL}\u@\h:\w\$ '
fi
...
```

Then, I can see how deep I am:

```
walt@bat:~(1)$ ed foo
263
!bash
+walt@bat:~(0)$ bash
++walt@bat:~(0)$ bash
+++walt@bat:~(0)$ exit
exit
++walt@bat:~(0)$ exit
exit
+walt@bat:~(0)$ exit
exit
!
q
walt@bat:~(0)$
```

Answer (score 4):

**awk:**

```bsh
# Count the occurrence of (sh)ells.
DEPTH_REGEX='^(ash|bash|busybox|csh|dash|fish|mksh|sh|tcsh|zsh)$'

DEPTH=$(/bin/ps -s $(/bin/ps -p $$ -osid --no-headers) -ocomm --no-headers | \
awk -v R=$DEPTH_REGEX '{for (A=1; A<=(NR-2); A++) {if ($A ~ R) {B++}}} END {print B}')
```

**pgrep:**

```bsh
DEPTH=$(/usr/bin/pgrep -c -s $(/bin/ps -p $$ -osid --no-headers) '^(ash|bash|busybox|csh|dash|fish|mksh|sh|tcsh|zsh)$')
```

You can place one of the two versions in a file and use source to make $DEPTH available.

```bsh
# Set 256 colors in terminal.
if [ -x /usr/bin/tput ] && [ "$(SHELL=/bin/sh tput colors)" -ge 8 ]; then
    export TERM="xterm-256color"
fi

# change these if you don't dig my colors!

NM="\[\033[0;1;37m\]"   #means no background and white lines
HI="\[\033[0;37m\]"     #change this for letter colors
SI="\[\033[38;5;202m\]" #this is for the current directory
NI="\[\033[0;1;30m\]"   #for @ symbol
IN="\[\033[0m\]"

# Count the occurrence of (sh)ells.
source /usr/share/shell-depth/depth

PS1="${NM}[${HI}\u${NI}@${HI}\h ${SI}\w${NM} \A](${HI}${DEPTH}${NM}): ${IN}"
```

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use `ps` without any additional arguments to see the whole shell stack (including the current one). It will be also showing all the background jobs you've started as well as `ps` itself, but it can give you a rough estimate of how deep you are.

Comment: This works `{ echo hello world; ps; } &` to prove the `ps` answer above.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix, I mean something like this: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/6Kfg8TqR9V/

Comment: Is there a way to mimic pstree -s $$ with ps?