# What is 'bash' command in bash?

Tags: command-line, bash

I just typed `bash` in Ubuntu's terminal and, it was like normal. But after that, I had to type exit twice. What is `bash` command in bash?

Comment: I think these topics could be interesting for you: [How do I know how many sub-shells deep I am?](https://askubuntu.com/q/1177123/566421) and [How can I get help on terminal commands?](https://askubuntu.com/q/991946/566421)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There is a difference between shells and terminal emulators.

Shell is a thing that passes your commands to the kernel, and that is executed. And terminal emulator programs let you interact with the shell. Examples of Terminal emualtors are `gnome-terminal`,`konsole` and shells are `bash`,`zsh`,`sh` etc. Terminal emulators are simply named as Terminal in most desktop environments.

When you open Terminal, it uses a shell by default. For most terminals it is `bash`. You can change the default shell. First run `whoami` to get your user name. Then run `cat /etc/passwd | grep user_name` where `user_name` is your user name. The last word is your default shell. Now you can change your shell with `sudo usermod --shell /bin/shell_name user_name`.

Also when you type `bash` it just opens another shell. You can simply exit the other shell by running `exit`. Such as executing `zsh` or `sh` will take you to other shell. You can read the man pages of shell with `man shell_name` to learn the differences between shells. However the man pages are extremely large and complicated to read that it will make your head spin. Executing a `man shell_name | wc -l` will give you the line count.

Hope that helps

Comment: `cat xxx | grep yyy` is a useless use of `cat`: `grep` can read files by itself: `grep user_name /etc/passwd`.

Comment: Why usermod over chsh?

Comment: yeah use chsh - you don't need to sudo for that.

Comment: "Shell is a thing that passes your commands to the kernel".. misleading nonsense.  What does this have to do with the kernel?  A shell allows you to execute commands in your path, provides some facilities to the OS API (like listing directories and the like), and sometimes provides a simple language for automating tasks.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas, what the shell has to do with the kernel is that the shell parses the command line and makes the system call asking the kernel to start a process. The shell  doesn't exactly handle any of the low-level stuff of launching a process itself.

Comment: @ilkkachu, The word "kernel" is just a distraction from the answer to the OP's question. `/bin/bash` is a _program_ whose purpose is to interpret the commands that you type by running other programs. Yeah, there's "kernel" and "system call" in the details of how it works. But OP's question wasn't about how it works. The question is about what it does.

Comment: @SolomonSlow, hey, they asked "what it has to do with the kernel", and my answer is that it's the kernel that handles the actual launching of the new process. Now, if the answer here is wrong there's always the option of proposing an edit to it...

Answer (score 36):

`bash` is a command interpreter, a shell, a program with an interface that interprets the commands that you put into it.

When you call `bash` from `bash`, you simply start a new shell 'inside' the original shell. When you exit from this second shell, you return to the original shell. You can exit from each shell with the `exit` command.

Comment: If you have a number of sudo commands to run, you can `sudo bash` to start a root bash, and exit from it back into your user-level bash. This saves multiple password entries, and it changes the prompt to remind you not to do anything bad while you are root.

Comment: @Paul_Pedant, That's right. And it is useful when you use redirection of output. On the other hand, sudo permissions will stay for 10 or 15 minutes, so you need no password for new sudo commands during that interval.

Comment: @sudodus no need for password indeed but you still need to type `sudo ` …

Comment: I had RHEL at a client site, and their sudoers policy was set to 5 minutes. Unfortunately my thinking time is 6 minutes. My current use for typing `bash` is so I can set PS1 to not have my details when I post commands to forums, and then go back to normal easily.

Comment: Creating a new subshell would re-source `.Xrc`, where `X` can be replaced by shells like `bash`, `zsh`, `ash`, etc.

Comment: @Paul_Pedant You're right, but the more appropriate way to do it is `sudo -s` (shell) or `sudo -i` (login shell).

Answer (score 5):

When you run bash in an existing shell, this starts a new bash shell as a child process of the one you were using.

You can see this in your Linux environment with the ps command:

```
    $ ps xjf
 PPID   PID  PGID   SID TTY      TPGID STAT   UID   TIME COMMAND
20282 20286 20282 20282 ?           -1 S    26075   0:00 sshd: john@pts/0
20286 20287 20287 20287 pts/0    32674 Ss   26075   0:00  \_ -bash
20287 32135 32135 20287 pts/0    32674 S    26075   0:00      \_ bash
32135 32674 32674 20287 pts/0    32674 R+   26075   0:00          \_ ps xjf
```

The reason you have to type exit twice to get out is that the first exit is exiting the child bash (process ID 32135 in this example), then the second exits the original bash (PID 20287 here).

If for some reason you wanted to start a new bash (or other shell) and knew that you were not going to want to return control to the original (parent) bash shell but instead to end your session, you could start the new bash via the exec command, which replaces your current running shell with the new process.
(it actually keeps the same process ID, even if you change to a new shell like ksh via the exec command):

```
$ ps -f
UID        PID  PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
john      3463 20287  0 13:47 pts/0    00:00:00 ps -f
john     20287 20286  0 06:11 pts/0    00:00:00 bash
$ exec ksh
$ ps -f
UID        PID  PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
john      3471 20287  0 13:47 pts/0    00:00:00 ps -f
john     20287 20286  0 06:11 pts/0    00:00:00 ksh
```

(note both the original bash and the ksh that replaced it have PID 20287)

By using exec this way, when you exit the child bash, the parent has already gone, so you will end your session.

Side notes:
One benefit of the exec bash is a quicker logout.

exec also uses less resources because the original shell has been replaced (the opposite of a bash fork bomb which consumes resources by starting many shells)

Beyond just launching shells, exec can let you give someone else access to something via your login, and make sure they're not left in your shell after they exit - e.g. I go to a colleague's desk, login as me and exec sudo (some command) or exec ssh (somewhere else) for them. Once they end that, it closes their terminal session instead of dropping them back to my login shell. (...but don't mess up logging in, or it will close your session when it would have normally returned to your shell)

Comment: Why anyone need to run bash inside bash?

Comment: @quantum231 a common reason to start a new shell is to be able to temporarily modify your environment for a particular task - e.g. set your $PATH, change your directory, set/change specific environment variables to launch a particular application. Then when you exit that shell you go back to the environment you were using in the directory you were in before you started it.

Answer (score 3):

When in the terminal you type, e.g., `zsh` <kbd>ret</kbd> you enter the Zshell and you operate using the syntax and the builtins of that shell, until you type `exit` <kbd>ret</kbd>.

You would probably notice the difference if your **default** shell were Bash!

Now what happens when, from the command prompt of your default shell (i.e., Bash), you type `bash` <kbd>ret</kbd>? Exactly what happened before with the Zshell, except that it's harder to tell what is different because you'll use the same syntax, the same builtins and the same aliases/shell functions as before!

But there are a number of differences,  possibly the most apparent the environment variable `SHLV` that Bash increments each time it's started.

Comment: `zsh` isn't installed by default in Ubuntu. You can observe similar behaviour with `sh` (which is a symlink to dash and is pre-installed). When you call `sh` from `bash`, the prompt would change to `$` from `username@host:~$`. You can try bash specific things to verify that you're in `sh`. For example, sh doesn't support brace expansions. When `echo {1..5}` is run in sh, you'll get `{1..5}` but in bash, you'll get `1 2 3 4 5`.

Answer (score 1):

Late to the party, but IMO, other answers don't get right to the point.

`bash` is a *program* whose purpose is to interpret your commands by running other programs. It's quite sophisticated--there's a lot of fancy ways you can construct a `bash` command--but the *simplest* command that you can type to `bash` is just the name of some other program.

If you type `foo` at the command prompt, `bash` will search for a program named `foo`, and if it finds one, it runs the program, it waits for the program to finish, and then it prints another prompt.

So, guess what happens if you type `bash` at the command prompt...

Answer (score -1):

The `bash` command is an shell that is installed always and you CANT remove this shell you better see [information here](https://opensource.com/resources/what-bash)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1282448)